# Vue 3 CSP - EvalError: Refused to evaluate a string as JavaScript

Tags: node.js, vue.js, express, vuejs3, content-security-policy

I am developing a web app using Vue 3 and Node/Express. When serving the built frontend code, I get the following error:

```
EvalError: Refused to evaluate a string as JavaScript because 'unsafe-eval' is not an allowed 
source of script in the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'".

    at new Function (<anonymous>)
    ...etc
```

This issue only seems to occur on page reload - when the page is first loaded, there are no errors

When looking into the issue online I could only find Vue docs referencing CSP issues for Vue 2, not Vue 3. Does anyone know a solution to this? Adding 'unsafe-eval' to my CSP header is an option if necessary, but I am wondering if there is a safer alternative?

Removing helmet.js usage from the express server does of course also solve the problem, but only because this removes the CSP header it was adding. I'd like to try to find a solution that avoids allowing unsafe-eval

Comment: Assuming you're using Vite + Express, you can give a try to the 2 first links available here: https://search.brave.com/search?spellcheck=0&q=vite+vue+js+csp

Comment: Mainly, there should not be a lot of differences between Vue2 and Vue3, minor webpack/Vite syntax changes but the idea is the same I think.

Comment: Nothing seems to cover the eval() issue. From what I've heard it's used internally by Vue so 'unsafe-eval' seems to be the only option

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to rewrite the offending code (as long as you can easily modify that code though). See the section "Eval and related functions are disabled" of https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/extensions-chromium/store-policies/csp.

Comment: Thanks for the link - unfortunately it seems Vue uses eval(), new Function(), etc. in the code produced when the project is built. I don't think there is any way to avoid it